# Unmodified OpenGeo Suite Geoexplorer proxy fails with HTTP 500, regardless of servlet

Tags: boundless-suite, proxy, windows-server-2008, ows

We're running an OpenGeo Suite (3.0.1 currently) and an unknown amount of time ago the proxy redirects to other data stores GeoExplorer does* started failing with HTTP 500 (Internal server error).

*
    var app = new GeoExplorer.Composer({
            authStatus: {{status}},
            proxy: "../proxy/?url=",

applied to every store with an absolute URL(doesn't matter whether valid or not),

like the default

```
suite: {url: "http://v2.suite.opengeo.org/geoserver/ows
```

so that the first call becomes

`GET /geoexplorer/proxy/?url=http://v2.suite.opengeo.org/geoserver/ows?_dc=4734342332&SERVICE=WMS`.

In this environment a newly installed and unmodified Suite does this, and an unmodified GeoExplorer webapp does the same thing in Tomcat. The specific error, same from jetty as Tomcat, is "*Error: No valid JSGI response: [object Object] (ringo/jsgi/connector.js#88)*".

The environment is a Windows Server 2008. In other environments (on other machines) the Suite has no such issues, so I'm wondering whether it has to do with some network setting or other in Windows?

Further, I'm not completely sure what this proxy is for and have been unable to find any documentation for it.

**Edit** 
Further research has revealed that this error message (HTTP500, ringo/jsgi/connector.js:88) appears if the machine hosting the servlet has no internet connection. It has been observed on a different machine, running Win 7. I wonder if the servlets in the affected Win 2008 server environment are somehow prevented from reaching the internet, and if this can be detected in any logs / audit files of Win 2008 server R2?